# How can I execute default route commands at startup (two NICs)?

Tags: networking, server

So I've got one server box that has two network cards. One connects to the Internet via ISP router (and serves a website) and one connects to a LAN.
The thing is that in order for everything to work right, I need after each reboot to run these commands:

```
sudo route del default gw 192.168.10.1   #the gateway of the LAN card
sudo route add default gw 10.10.10.1     #the gateway of the ISP router card
```

My question is, how can I make these commands run automatically at system reboot (and not at any user logon, as nobody logs into the box)?